# how to display sql result in a table grouped by names by using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

we were given a school project and I don't know how to go about it.
So the thing is that we were to make a database for a business; ours is a beauty salon.
My problem now is how to display the data from the query in a table.

I have taken a look at a previous post which seems to be an answer, but i don't know how it really works for my case

[stackoverflow question: group query results in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882689/group-query-results-in-php)

So i have here the current result and a gist of how i want it to look like. Basically i want the employee names to span multiple rows equal to the number of services they provided.

[image]

This is currently my code:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $error == '') { 
echo "<table width='auto' border='1' class='center'>
<tr>
<th scope='col'>Transaction No.</th>
<th scope='col'>Service Name</th>
<th scope='col'>Employee Name</th>
<th scope='col'>Date</th>
<th scope='col'>Adjusted Price </th>
<th scope='col'>Adjusted Cost </th>
<th scope='col'>Adjusted Parlor Dividend</th>
<th scope='col'>Adjusted Employee Dividend</th>
</tr>";
$res=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT serviceline.transnum, servicelist.srvnam, employeelist.empname, serviceline.transdate, serviceline.priceadj, serviceline.costadj, serviceline.pardivadj, servicelist.price, serviceline.empdivadj, servicelist.cost, servicelist.pardiv, servicelist.empdiv FROM EmployeeList INNER JOIN (ServiceList INNER JOIN ServiceLine ON ServiceList.SrvID = ServiceLine.SrvID) ON EmployeeList.EmpID = ServiceLine.EmpID WHERE DATE(serviceline.transdate) BETWEEN '".$fyear."-".$fmon."-01' AND '".$tyear."-".$tmon."-31'");
while($ent=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
 {
 $adjprc=$ent['priceadj']+$ent['price'];
 $adjcst=$ent['costadj']+$ent['cost'];
 $adjpardiv=$ent['pardivadj']+$ent['pardiv'];
 $adjempdiv=$ent['empdivadj']+$ent['empdiv'];
 echo "<tr>
<th scope='row' e>".$ent['transnum']."</th>
<td>".$ent['srvnam']."</td>
<td>".$ent['empname']."</td>
<td>".$ent['transdate']."</td>
<td>Php ".number_format($adjprc, 2, '.', '')."</td>
<td>Php ".number_format($adjcst, 2, '.', '')."</td>
<td>Php ".number_format($adjpardiv, 2, '.', '')."</td>
<td>Php ".number_format($adjempdiv, 2, '.', '')."</td>
 </tr>
 ";}
echo "</table>";
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should (and as a good habit) use the ORDER BY clause to sort the query results, ensuring your data is consistently returned to your PHP   page. For this problem, you will want to sort by the name and then their service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in one table like your current code, you will need to add `rowspan=xx` to the cell, which means you need to know the number of rows for each name, so you have to add sub-query with `COUNT()` to your current query.

Alternatively, you can use nested tables. So you have the main table with two cells for each row, one for name and another with a nested table for all the other fields. Something like:

```
$last_emp="";
while($ent=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
 $adjprc=$ent['priceadj']+$ent['price'];
 $adjcst=$ent['costadj']+$ent['cost'];
 $adjpardiv=$ent['pardivadj']+$ent['pardiv'];
 $adjempdiv=$ent['empdivadj']+$ent['empdiv'];

 if($last_emp != $ent['empname'])
 {
   if($last_emp != "")
   {
     echo "</table><td/></tr>";
   }
   echo "<tr>
   <td>".$ent['empname']."</td>
   <td><table>";
 }
 echo "<tr>";
 <td>".$ent['transdate']."</td>
 <td>Php ".number_format($adjprc, 2, '.', '')."</td>
 <td>Php ".number_format($adjcst, 2, '.', '')."</td>
 <td>Php ".number_format($adjpardiv, 2, '.', '')."</td>
 <td>Php ".number_format($adjempdiv, 2, '.', '')."</td>
 </tr>
 if($last_emp != $ent['empname'])
 {
   $last_emp = $ent['empname'];
 }
}
```

Comment: i copied this and edited some syntax errors, but the end result is not quite as expected. ![Current Output](http://i62.tinypic.com/2vtcrol.png). It looks like separate tables with only a single row for each table.

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited my answer. Please try it and feel free to correct syntax errors. I don't have PHP installed so I'm writing from memory.