# Grouping certain columns with details and calculate

Tags: php, sql-server

The SQL Server 2008 data :

```
ETA         VESSEL     SHIPPER      PRODUCT       QTY      SURVEYOR
---         ------     -------      -------       ---      --------
01/05/2016  VSL A      CUST A       MILK          10       K
01/05/2016  VSL A      CUST B       VEG           12       L
02/05/2016  VSL B      CUST X       RICE          11       M
02/05/2016  VSL B      CUST Y       BREAD         13       N
```

The desired output :

```
ETA         VESSEL     SHIPPER      PRODUCT       QTY      SURVEYOR
---         ------     -------      -------       ---      --------
01/05/2016  VSL A      CUST A       MILK          10       K
                       CUST B       VEG           12       L
                                                  ---
                                                  22

02/05/2016  VSL B      CUST X       RICE          11       M
                       CUST Y       BREAD         13       N
                                                  ---
                                                  24
```

I want to produce the above results in PHP with grouping ETA and VESSEL. Most likely it will involved with nested loop or foreach. But I don't know how to start with it.

Comment: data is grouped on ETA and Vessal

Comment: yes. and have subtotal for each vessel.

Comment: http://demo.koolphp.net/Examples/KoolGrid/Grouping/Initial_Grouping/index.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882689/group-query-results-in-php

Comment: still not clear

Comment: read all links it is ...

Comment: i read all of it. but still not help at all.

Comment: have you read example  under Description & Sample code http://demo.koolphp.net/Examples/KoolGrid/Grouping/Initial_Grouping/index.php